# Jsonp - Response from server

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp, cors

To solve single origin policy we can use either Cross origin resource sharing (CORS) or Jsonp..
    In case of CORS,we may not have access to server.. so many ppl are suggesting us to go for Jsonp.
    But in Jsonp also only if the server sends the response as proper javascript, we are able to evaluate the response.
      For eg: The function call appended ..
The response in this cause may be like this.. "parseJson(data)"

now, my question is.

How can we ensure that server will giv proper response (proper Javascript)?

Assume that we don have access to server, wht to do in this case?

Shd we have something like proxy in-between?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a proxy server is the best route when you don't have access to the server response. You are right in that both CORS and JSONP need some special formatting from the server.